# Error calling an external SOAP web service with WSClient

Tags: web-services, grails, soap

I have created a SOAP webservice that I would like to access from Grails.

I have installed the plugin ws-client in order to use the object WSClient.

I have tried with the example given here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+WSClient+in+Grails

So my code is:

```
def index = { 

def proxy = new WSClient("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL", this.class.classLoader)
proxy.initialize()

def result = proxy.CelsiusToFahrenheit(0) 
result = "You are probably freezing at ${result} degrees Farhenheit" 
flash.message = result 
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
 javac: target release 1.5 conflicts with default source release 1.7
| Error 2013-02-27 17:47:06,901 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - JAXBException occurred when processing request: [POST] /WordGame/game/create
"org.tempuri" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index. Stacktrace follows:
Message: "org.tempuri" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    Line | Method
->>  197 | createContext in com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    172 | newInstance   in javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder
|    132 | newInstance . in     ''
|    334 | find          in     ''
|    431 | newInstance . in javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
|    349 | createClient  in org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory
|    196 | createClient  in     ''
|    175 | createClient  in     ''
|    198 | createClient  in groovyx.net.ws.AbstractCXFWSClient
|    107 | initialize    in groovyx.net.ws.WSClient
|     30 | conversion .  in wordgame.GameController$$ENyfXWG9
|     42 | doCall        in wordgame.GameController$_closure1$$ENyfXWG9
|    195 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I know there is no error calling the method proxy.CelsiusToFahrenheit(0) because I have the same error just doing:

```
def proxy = new WSClient("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL", this.class.classLoader)
proxy.initialize()
```

I have tried with an other webservice I have created but I have the same error.

I have search on Google and I have seen a lot of people having this issue and I didn't find how to fix it.

Config:
Windows 7 x64
Netbeans 7.2.1
Grails 2.2.0

Do someone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer but the problem was from plugins. In order to work, It was needed to install the plugins:

cxf

cxf-client

Installing these two plugins resolved the problem.

Comment: I found ws-client plugin http://grails.org/plugin/ws-client much groovier to use. Though installing cxf is required.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message

```
javac: target release 1.5 conflicts with default source release 1.7
```

I think it's about JDK version. WSClient needs JDK to compile something in the run-time, so you have to deploy a 1.7 version JDK to support that.

Comment: This message just disappeared when I have installed the cxf plugins